# jQuery fixed sidebar that moves with content if overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yFjtt/1/

The idea is that the user can scroll PAST the header to make the sidebar 'stick' in place while they scroll further down the page.

As they near the bottom of the page it should then work out how much space is left and how much space the sidebar needs and the add some negative margin to move the sidebar upwards whilst maintaining the fixed position.

Upto here it all works fine.

The next problem is making sure that the sidebar only moves up as far as it needs to and should remain about 10 pixels from the bottom. This way the sidebar will be fixed until it needs to move upward to reveal its content and then once it's all shown become stuck again about 10 pixels from the bottom.

Here is where I have tried to achieve this (see fiddle for full code):

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() > (documentHeight - sidebarHeight) ) {

        if( offsetBottom < 10) {

        }
        else {
            $('div.sidebar').stop(true,false);
            $('div.sidebar').animate({'margin-top':offset}, 300);
        }

    } else {
        $('div.sidebar').stop(true,true);
        $('div.sidebar').css({'margin-top':'0'});
    }
```

However the sidebar STILL moves too far up the page... Can anyone help? I'm sure it's just a simple mistake working out the offset from the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had a good try, except I'm not sure what those animations are doing there. Basically you need 3 checks, first to see if the use is above the header, second to check if they're between the header and the bottom most limit for the sidebar, and lastly if they're below that point. Then simply swap and change classes and modify top value as necessary.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFjtt/19/)

```
var sidebarHeight = $('div.sidebar').height();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
var headerHeight = $('div.header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var margin = 10;

    var sidebar_offset = documentHeight - sidebarHeight - (margin * 2); // double margin to account for top and bottom margins

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight && $(window).scrollTop() < sidebar_offset ) {
        // below header, but above the sidebar offset limit
        $('div.sidebar').addClass('fixed');  
        $('div.sidebar').css('top', '');    
    }
    else if ( $(window).scrollTop() <= headerHeight ) {
        // above header
        $('div.sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        $('div.sidebar').css('top', ''); 
    }
    else {
        // past the sidebar offset limit
        $('div.sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        $('div.sidebar').css('top', documentHeight - sidebarHeight - margin);
    }
});​
```